# Removing NAs with `na.omit()` vs `is.na()` - not identical?

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

Removing NAs from a dataframe can be done either with `na.omit` or manually by using `is.na` and subsetting. However, the results are not identical (with `identical`). Only when the result of `na.omit` is wrapped in a `data.frame`, the results are identical.

Here is an MWE:

```r
data <- data.frame(
    x1 = c(1, 2, NA, 5, 9, 7, NA),
    x2 = c(11, 1, 6, 1, 7, 9, 1),
    x3 = c(5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 1, 6)
)
data

# na.omit() function
data_omit <- na.omit(data)
# manually with is.na()
data_manual <- data[!(is.na(data$x1)), ]
# check
identical(data_omit, data_manual)  # returns FALSE
# wrap in data.frame() and check again
identical(data.frame(data_omit), data_manual)  # returns TRUE
```

This is strange as the class of all three the options is `data.frame`:

```
> class(data_omit)
[1] "data.frame"
> class(data.frame(data_omit))
[1] "data.frame"
> class(data_manual)
[1] "data.frame"
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: Even if they have the same values, they are different objects, try `attributes(data_omit)` and `attributes(data_manual)`, na.omit keeps information about which values were removed in attributes.

Comment: To check the columns themselces you can use: `mapply(all.equal, data_omit, data_manual)`

Comment: Ok, I see! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that `na.omit` not only removes cases, but also adds the row numbers of the removed cases to the `"na.action"` attribute of the result (which attribute's class is `"omit"`). ([Source: `?na.omit`](http://127.0.0.1:26373/library/stats/html/na.fail.html))

In your case the difference is:

```r
attributes(data_omit)

$names
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 4 5 6

$class
[1] "data.frame"

$na.action
3 7 
3 7 
attr(,"class")
[1] "omit"
```

```r
attributes(data_manual)

$names
[1] "x1" "x2" "x3"

$row.names
[1] 1 2 4 5 6

$class
[1] "data.frame"
```